# How to start Google App Engine via sub folder?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, cloud

I've downloaded the Google Cloud SDK to my Mac and have installed it.  I have a local Google App Engine based app that I'd like to run from a sub folder off my user root folder.  I'm not sure what the syntax should look like though to start the server.

I can run the server directly from my user folder without issue:

```
dev_appserver.py appengine-python
```

Where appengine-python is the folder with all of the app files.  I can view this app in a browser without any problems.

If I move appengine-python into the documents folder, I can't run it.  For example, the following throws an error:

```
dev_appserver.py documents\appengine-python

No such file or directory: 'documentsappengine-python'
```

What should the above path syntax look like?

Comment: aren't you using the wrong slash?? it should be `/` instead of `\\`

Comment: Perfect. You are correct.  Can you add as answer?

Comment: Will do I was off for 4 days
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Unix based systems, (which include Mac), the forward slash `/` is used to seperate the file system objects. So inorder to seperate the `documents` and `app-engine` forward slash `/` must be used, instead of the backward slash.

The correct syntax is,
`dev_appserver.py documents/appengine-python`

Also, the forwward slash has a special meaning in Unix, as it represent the `root` directory. Hence every  absolute path begins with `/` and the different file or directories are further seperated using `/`